# Rearranging the square

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

You are given a square piece of paper. You can cut it into pieces and rearrange them to form a new shape. You are allowed to rotate and flip pieces, provided that they are all used. Can you cut the square into pieces to form these shapes?

1. An equilateral triangle.
2. A regular hexagon.
3. A regular octagon.

**Bonus:** What is the minimum number of pieces needed for each shape?

Comment: Must the pieces have Jordan curve boundary and are you assuming the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @hexomino I am not really sure what these mean? The piece shape can be arbitrary - whatever you can cut from the original paper.

Comment: It's just that I know the answer to 4 already but it depends a lot on your definition of pieces.

Comment: I suspected that you were referring to 4. Ok I allow any definition that provides a nice answer :)

Comment: Do the final shapes have to have the same area as the original?

Comment: "This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined." I think it applies to this question, as "piece" is not defined here. For example, let's say we break everything into atoms and recombine them. In purely mathematical terms, there exist bijections between any of these shapes (viewed as set of points) because they all have the same cardinality.

Comment: I've seen construction for 1.  a few times already. If you [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rearrange+a+square+into+a+triangle&tbm=isch) you can easily find [pictures](https://www.cutoutfoldup.com/images/0109-i.png) and [animations](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EquilateralTriangleToSquare/). Now if we know 1. then 2. is easy and I assume 3. is similar. (More interesting question for 2. and 3. would be the minimal number of cuts.) But the last one will depend on your definitions and axioms as hexomino pointed out.

Comment: final shapes have the same area as original.

Comment: I removed the circle as it's too speculative. Also added bonus question about minimising pieces.

Comment: Is every cut precisely a straight line that splits a piece being cut into exactly two more pieces? Or can we "use scissors"? For example, make a couple "half-way" cuts that only split a piece once they all join in a point?; or for another example, make a cut consisting of joined line segments?; or for example, "slide scissors" to make curved cuts?...

Comment: Or... are you talking about "[dissections](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html)"?  In that case, for example, a minimal solution is known for 1. and 3. (for triangle and octagon). If this is the case, then 4. the circle can also be "dissected" into a square, in finitely many steps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my last comment on the question, then the answer is

> Yes.
>  
>  This is due to [Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wallace-Bolyai-GerwienTheorem.html): *"Two polygons are congruent by [dissection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html) iff they have the same area. In particular, any polygon is congruent by [dissection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html) to a square of the same area".*

For the bonus, the best known dissections are

> due to *Theobald, G. "Geometric Dissections."*
>  
>  [image]

For the original question (before the circle was removed),

> *"Laczkovich (1988) also proved that a circle is congruent by dissection to a square (furthermore, the dissection can be accomplished using translations only)."* 
>  ~ *"Weisstein, Eric W. "Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource."* 
>  ~ *"Laczkovich, M. "Von Neumann's Paradox with Translation." Fund. Math. 131, 1-12, 1988."*

Comment: Correct! This is the answer I was looking for. I was surprised that a circle can be done too.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Note that the [circle proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_circle-squaring_problem) relies on axiom of choice and on non-measurable subsets (This is one of the reasons why hexomino asked for clarifications).

Comment: Vepir thanks for the clarification. I also wonder if curved cuts can be used? I posted a new puzzle about this topic: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110080/dissecting-the-square